# Apache Phoenix query performance improvement

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

We are trying to improve the read performance of our HBase setup using the Apache Phoenix drivers against a data set of **~ 11.5 M** records.

> HBase 0.98
>   Apache Phoenix driver 4.3.1
>   Squirrel Client 3.2

The table comprises of **21 columns**, below is the DDL statement:

```
create table *table_name* (PKEY BIGINT not null primary key,DATE_KEY BIGINT,TIMEOFDAY_KEY BIGINT,GMT_TZ_PKEY BIGINT,FACT_DATE TIMESTAMP,PAGE_KEY BIGINT,FFER_KEY BIGINT,OFFER_TYPE_KEY BIGINT,SESSION_KEY BIGINT,CUSTOMER_KEY BIGINT,VISITS_CNTR BIGINT,ELIGIBLE_CNTR smallint,  PRESENTED_CNTR smallint,ACCEPTED smallint,  ACCEPTED_CLICK smallint,FIRST_RESPONSE_CNTR smallint,REJECTED_CNTR smallint,IS_FIXED smallint,  IGNORED_CNTR smallint,ENGAGED_CNTR smallint,CONVERTED_CNTR smallint)
```

We have performed salting on the table (**salt_buckets = 3**) and created a secondary index on all the columns (immutable indexing).

We are executing the following queries, with the corresponding times as mention in the Squirrel client:

```
Select count(*) from *table_name* :   
Query Time (A) = 0.031 s  
Transport time (B) = 2.631 s  
Total Execution Time (A+B)  = 2.661 s
```

Execution Plan:

```
PLAN  
CLIENT 6-CHUNK PARALLEL 6-WAY 
FULL SCAN OVER OFR_FCT_IDX_SALTED  
SERVER FILTER BY FIRST KEY ONLY  
SERVER AGGREGATE INTO SINGLE ROW  
CLIENT 100 ROW LIMIT

select MAX(session_key) from *table_name* group by TIMEOFDAY_KEY having count(SESSION_KEY) > 100 order by TIMEOFDAY_KEY : Rows returned 431   
Query Time (A) = 0.04 s  
Transport time (B) = 11.894 s  
Total Execution Time (A+B)  = 11.934 s
```

Execution Plan:

```
PLAN  
CLIENT 6-CHUNK PARALLEL 6-WAY FULL SCAN OVER OFR_FCT_IDX_SALTED  
SERVER FILTER BY FIRST KEY ONLY  SERVER AGGREGATE INTO DISTINCT ROWS BY ["TIMEOFDAY_KEY"]  
CLIENT MERGE SORT  
CLIENT FILTER BY COUNT(TO_BIGINT("SESSION_KEY")) > 100  
CLIENT SORTED BY ["TIMEOFDAY_KEY"]
```

As you can see, the query times are great but the Transport time (reading/output time) appears to be pretty high.

My questions are following:

1. Do these results appear in tune with what we should expect for the
   mentioned data set? Considering the latest performance test results:
   [Latest Performance Test](http://phoenix-bin.github.io/client/performance/latest.htm)
2. Can we somehow improve the performance of the transport time(reading
   time) further?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to at least Apache Phoenix 4.7, apparently, they started using protobuf as the default serialization method (over JSON).